# Difference between 'With regard to' and 'In accordance with'

Tags: sentence-construction, exam-questions

> _________ your instructions, we have closed your bank account.
>
> (a) With regard to
> (b) In accordance with

My guess is it should be "In accordance with" but my book gave the other option (with regard to).

Which option fits well here? Why not the other one?

Comment: Hi @Abhi. It is better that you provide the answer you have in mind, and your reason for choosing that answer. That way, we'll have a better view, re: confusion/doubts.

Comment: "accordance" would not be capitalized, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> (b) In accordance with...

is like saying *Following...*

> **Following** your instructions, we have closed your bank account.

I think this is the intended meaning in context, as you generally have the right to close a bank account.

> (a) With regard to...

is like saying *Considering...*

This would be OK if the result might not be as instructed, but not in a case where you expect your instructions to be carried out.

> **With regard to/Regarding/Considering** your request for a million dollar loan, unfortunately we cannot help you.